# Django channels websocket not receiving data sent

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm currently learning how to use Django channels for websocket connections and so far I've gotten the websocket to actually connect, but when I send it data it doesn't receive it.

This is my consumers.py

```
class WSConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('connected', event)
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'message': 'TEST'
        })
        print('sent')

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print('disconnected', event)

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print('received', event))
```

This is my javascript on the front end

```
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

    const WSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/room/'
        + roomName
        + '/'
    );

    WSocket.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log('websocket has connected');
    };

    WSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    };


    WSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('websocket closed unexpectedly');
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Woops just realized I'm a fool in a man's shoes.

In the below code I originally wrote

```
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'message': 'TEST'
        })
```

when it should be

```
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'text': 'TEST'
        })
```

It should have a 'text' type instead of 'message'